# Downloading contents in the pop window in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Need some help from shiny and java script experts here. I have a shiny application where you click on "More Info" you get a drop down with table. Again when you click on "Open Window", you get table contents. I need this table contents to be download when clicked on download button there (in the pop up window). I tried with below code but not getting

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(xtable)
library(shiny)


library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  samdt <- structure(list(Domain = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b","a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), 
                          sub_domain = c("a1", "a1", "b1", "a1", "b1","a1", "a1", "b1", "a1", "b1"), 
                          Reviews = c(1234, 2311, 3123, 4311, 5211,1,2,3,4,5),
                          Ratings = c(1,2,1,2,1,4,1,2,5,3),
                          text = c("asd","dfdsf","sdfs","sdfs","sdf","df","re","uy","ew","qw")), row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
  new_sam <- samdt %>% group_by(Domain) %>% summarise(nReviews = n()) %>% mutate(asd = round((nReviews * 100/sum(nReviews)),2))
  subs <- subs <- samdt %>% group_by(Domain, sub_domain) %>% summarise(nReviews = n(),
                                                                       table_html = purrr::pmap(list(toString(Ratings),toString(text),toString(Reviews)),
                                                                                  function(ca,cb,cc){
                                                                                    ca <- strsplit(ca,',')[[1]] 
                                                                                    cb <- strsplit(cb,',')[[1]] 
                                                                                    cc <- strsplit(cc,',')[[1]] 
                                                                                    ca <- (c(ca,''))[1:n()]
                                                                                    cb <- (c(cb,''))[1:n()]
                                                                                    cc <- (c(cc,''))[1:n()]
                                                                                    p1 <- '<table border=5><button onclick=\'exportTableToCSV(window,\'members.csv\');\'>Export HTML Table To CSV File</button><br><tr><th>Ratings</th><th>Text</th><th>Reviews</th></tr>'
                                                                                    p2 <- paste(glue::glue("<tr><td>{ca}</td><td>{cb}</td><td>{cc}</td></tr>"),collapse = '')
                                                                                    p3 <- '</table>'
                                                                                    paste(p1,p2,p3,sep='')
                                                                                  })) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(
                                                                                    rn=row_number(),
                                                                                    launcher_html = 
                                                                                      paste0(glue::glue('<script>  
  function openWindow{rn}() {{  
    var newtab{rn} = window.open("", "anotherWindow", "width=300,height=150");  
    newtab{rn}.document.open();
    newtab{rn}.document.write("{table_html}");
    newtab{rn}.exportTableToCSV = exportTableToCSV;
    newtab{rn}.downloadCSV = downloadCSV;
  }} 
  
</script>  
  
  <button onclick="openWindow{rn}()"> Open Window </button>  
   '),tags$script('function exportTableToCSV(scopedWindow,filename) {
                    alert("I am an alert box!");
                    var csv = [];
                    var rows = scopedWindow.document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

                        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
                            row.push(cols[j].innerText);

                        csv.push(row.join(","));
                    }

                    // Download CSV file
                    alert(\'Hey\')
                    scopedWindow.downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
                }'),
                                                                                             tags$script('function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
                    var csvFile;
                    var downloadLink;

                    // CSV file
                    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

                    // Download link
                    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

                    // File name
                    downloadLink.download = filename;

                    // Create a link to the file
                    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

                    // Hide download link
                    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

                    // Add the link to DOM
                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

                    // Click download link
                    downloadLink.click();
                }'))
                                                                                  ) %>%   group_by(Domain)  %>% mutate(asd = nReviews/sum(nReviews)) %>% select(-table_html) %>% nest() %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(
                                                                                    htmltab = HTML(print(xtable(data),type="HTML",
                                                                                                         sanitize.text.function=function(x)x))
                                                                                 )

  samdt_x <- left_join(new_sam,subs)
  
  add_collapse_content <- function(x, id) {
    tagList(
      tags$button(
        "data-toggle" = "collapse",
        "data-target" = paste0("#", id),
        "More Info"
      ),
      div(
        "id" = id,
        "class" = "collapse",
        x
      )
    )  %>% as.character()
  }
  
  samdt_x2 <- samdt_x %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(html_buttons = 
                                                 add_collapse_content(htmltab,Domain)) %>%
    relocate(html_buttons) %>% select(-data,-htmltab)
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(samdt_x2,rownames = F,escape = F, selection = 'none'
              ,options = list(
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = c(0))
                ))
    )})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```